# How to display the multiple records in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

One table having 3 records with same id.
please tell me how to display that records in entity framework?

Comment: Please post the code you have wrote to try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entity in entity framework must have unique identification. If you configured Id as entity key you will never display all of them without native ADO.NET. You must configure another property (or set of properties) as entity key. You should use primary key of the table for that.